# How to stop VS code from showing source control changes when changes made to untracked directories

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have a git repo with root directory `root`. I cloned another repo `first_dir` as subdirectory in `root`. I made a directory `resources` in `first_dir` that I want to put 1,000 files in. Because I do not intend to push these 1,000 files to a remote repo, I have added `first_dir/resources/` to my `.gitignore` in `root` prior to adding the 1,000 files.

Despite this, and adding `resources/` to the `.gitignore` in `first_dir`, VS code still shows 1,000 changes (in `first_dir` repo) for the addition of the files. It seems that git is correctly not tracking the files. And the source control in VS code for `first_dir` has a U next to each file I added.

My goal is for VS code to show 0 changes instead of 1,000 changes. The 1,000 changes are distracting and make it more difficult to see actual changes.

For clarity, my project is structured as follows:

```
root
|
|----first_dir
|
|--------.gitignore
|
|--------resources
|
|----.gitignore
```

**Contents of `root/.gitignore`**

```
first_dir/resources/
```

**Contents of `root/first_dir/.gitignore`**

```
./resources/
./resources/*
./resources
```

Comment: In my setup VS Code stops tracking as well, a few seconds after saving the .gitignore file. Maybe reload VS Code, or launch some reindexing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I didn't think this would matter, but changing `./resources/` to `resources/` in `root/first_dir/.gitignore` solved this problem.

Comment: `./` is not supported by gitignore. However, anything containing a forward slash (`/`) will automatically be treated with regard to the containing directory. If you want to ignore a file in the current directory, change it to `/file.name`.